# List files ONLY in the current directory

Tags: python

In Python, I only want to list all the files in the current directory ONLY. I do not want files listed from any sub directory or parent.

There do seem to be similar solutions out there, but they don't seem to work for me. Here's my code snippet:

```
import os
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    for file in files:
      do some stuff
      print file
```

Let's suppose I have 2 files, holygrail.py and Tim inside my current directory. I have a folder as well and it contains two files - let's call them Arthur and Lancelot - inside it. When I run the script, this is what I get:

```
holygrail.py
Tim
Arthur
Lancelot
```

I am happy with holygrail.py and Tim. But the two files, Arthur and Lancelot, I do not want listed.

Answer (score 545, accepted):

Just use [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.listdir) and [`os.path.isfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) instead of [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.walk).

**Example:**

```
import os
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    # do something
```

---

But be careful while applying this to other directory, like

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(somedir) if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

which would not work because `f` is not a full path but relative to the current directory.

Therefore, for filtering on another directory, do `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(somedir, f))`

*(Thanks [Causality](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1311956/causality) for the hint)*

Comment: This is what I needed in the end `[os.path.join(path_base,f) for f in os.listdir(path_base) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path_base,f))]`

Comment: This is his answer:  `files = [f for f in os.listdir("/somedir") if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("/somedir", f))]'`

Answer (score 91):

You can use `os.listdir` for this purpose.  If you only want *files* and not *directories*, you can filter the results using `os.path.isfile`.

example:

```
files = os.listdir(os.curdir)  #files and directories
```

or

```
files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir( os.curdir ) )  # files only
files = [ f for f in os.listdir( os.curdir ) if os.path.isfile(f) ] #list comprehension version.
```

Comment: I think the filter version only works if it's curdir.  E.g. it won't work for  files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(anyFolderPath))?

Answer (score 30):

```
import os

destdir = '/var/tmp/testdir'

files = [ f for f in os.listdir(destdir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(destdir,f)) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the general solution (in the case where the dir is not the cwd).

Comment: Is there a way that file time stamp is also part of the out put?

Answer (score 19):

You can use `os.scandir()`. New function in stdlib starts from Python 3.5.

```
import os

for entry in os.scandir('.'):
    if entry.is_file():
        print(entry.name)
```

Faster than `os.listdir()`. `os.walk()` [implements](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#optimizations) `os.scandir()`.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module.

```
from pathlib import Path
x = Path('./')
print(list(filter(lambda y:y.is_file(), x.iterdir())))
```

Comment: This is really useful when using pathlib.Path. Usually I use pathlib.Path. Thank you very much.

Comment: using the `os` module covered in older solutions is fine, but starting to incorporate easier to use modules like `glob` and `pathlib` should be emphasized.

Answer (score 7):

this can be done with os.walk()

**python 3.5.2 tested;**

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.', topdown=True):
    dirs.clear() #with topdown true, this will prevent walk from going into subs
    for file in files:
      #do some stuff
      print(file)
```

remove the dirs.clear() line and the files in sub folders are included again.

update with **references**;

[os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) documented here and talks about the triple list being created and topdown effects.

[.clear()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html) documented here for emptying a list

so by clearing the relevant list from os.walk you can effect its result to your needs.

Answer (score 5):

```
import os
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    for file in files:
      do some stuff
      print file
```

You can improve this code with `del dirs[:]`which will be like following .

```
import os
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    del dirs[:]
    for file in files:
      do some stuff
      print file
```

Or even better if you could point os.walk with current working directory .

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(cwd, topdown=True):
    del dirs[:]  # remove the sub directories.
    for file in files:
      do some stuff
      print file
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of `os.walk`, just use `os.listdir`

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Pygirl and Flimm, use of [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), (really helpful reference, btw) their solution included the full path in the result, so here is a solution that outputs just the file names:

```py
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(destination_dir) # destination_dir = './' in original post
files = [x.name for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_file()]
print(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

To list files in a specific folder excluding files in its sub-folders with `os.walk` use:

```
_, _, file_list = next(os.walk(data_folder))
```