# Calculate MD5 of each file

Tags: python

I have two directories containing few files and I want to calculate the MD5 of each file in each of the directories and store the hashes in a per-directory list.

I can calculate the hashes of one file using the 
    import hashlib

library but can't figure out a way to do the above?

Comment: Hmm so what's your question?  You don't know how to walk a directory?

Answer (score 1):

See how calculating MD5 for some file sum in [enter link description here](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/02/md5-hash-of-file-in-python/). If you want to obtain a list of all files from directory see [List files in ONLY the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968976/python-list-files-in-the-current-directory-only).