# Python3 list files from particular directory

Tags: python, linux, file, python-3.x, filenames

How to list file names which are only from a particular directory? I don't want file names from sub-directory or anything.

Comment: Duplicate: [How to list all files of a directory in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3207219/5520354)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
os.listdir(dir)
```

Also see
[List files in ONLY the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968976/list-files-in-only-the-current-directory)