# Error in converting multiple FASTA files to Nexus using Biopython

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I want to convert multiple FASTA format files (DNA sequences) to the NEXUS format using BIO.SeqIO module but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fasta2nexus.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(process(fullpath))
  File "fasta2nexus.py", line 23, in process
    alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 1003, in convert
    with as_handle(in_file, in_mode) as in_handle:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/File.py", line 88, in as_handle
    with open(handleish, mode, **kwargs) as fp:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c'
```

What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
##!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function # or just use Python 3!

import fileinput
import os
import re
import sys

from Bio import SeqIO, Nexus
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC


test = "/Users/teton/Desktop/test"

files = os.listdir(os.curdir)

def process(filename):
    # retuns ("basename", "extension"), so [0] picks "basename"
    base = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] 
    return SeqIO.convert(filename, "fasta", 
                         base + ".nex", "nexus", 
                         alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)

for files in os.listdir(test):
    for file in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(file)
        print(process(fullpath))
```

Comment: Please include the entire traceback so we can see which line the error is raised at.

Comment: @Ramon PLEASE do not delete your original code and question, otherwise the answers don't match the questions. If you've changed your code and got a new error, just make edits at the bottom.

Comment: Ok, sorry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should solve the majority of problems I can see.

```
from __future__ import print_function # or just use Python 3!

import fileinput
import os
import re
import sys

from Bio import SeqIO, Nexus
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC

test = "/Users/teton/Desktop"

def process(filename):
    # retuns ("basename", "extension"), so [0] picks "basename"
    base = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] 
    return SeqIO.convert(filename, "fasta", 
                         base + ".nex", "nexus", 
                         alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)
    
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(test):
    for file in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, file)
        print(process(fullpath))
```

I changed a few things. First, I ordered your imports (personal thing) and made sure to import `IUPAC` from `Bio.Alphabet` so you can actually assign the correct alphabet to your sequences. Next, in your `process()` function, I added a line to split the extension off the filename, then used the full filename for the first argument, and just the base (without the extension) for naming the Nexus output file. Speaking of which, I assume you'll be using the `Nexus` module in later code? If not, you should remove it from the imports.

I wasn't sure what the point of the last snippet was, so I didn't include it. In it, though, you appear to be walking the file tree and `process()`ing each file *again*, then referencing some undefined variable named `count`. Instead, just run `process()` once, and do whatever `count` refers to within that loop.

You may want to consider adding some logic to your `for` loop to test that the file returned by `os.path.join()` actually *is* a FASTA file. Otherwise, if any other file type is in one of the directories you search and you `process()` it, all sorts of weird things could happen.

#### EDIT

OK, based on your new code I have a few suggestions. First, the line

```
files = os.listdir(os.curdir)
```

is completely unnecessary, as below the definition of the `process()` function, you're redefining the `files` variable. Additionally, the above line would fail, as you are not calling `os.curdir()`, you are just passing its reference to `os.listdir()`.

The code at the bottom should simply be this:

```
for file in os.listdir(test):
    print(process(file))
```

`for file in files` is redundant, and calling `os.path.join()` with a single argument does nothing.

Comment: Thank you! Can you change the code for only current directory. I got this error:   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/AlignIO/__init__.py", line 214, in write
    count = writer_class(fp).write_file(alignments)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/AlignIO/NexusIO.py", line 98, in write_file
    self.write_alignment(first_alignment)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/AlignIO/NexusIO.py", line 105, in write_alignment
    raise ValueError("Must have at least one sequence")
ValueError: Must have at least one sequence

Comment: @Ramon what do you mean, only the current directory? Just put whatever directory you want to scan in `test`.

Comment: I did, but it keep saying: ValueError: Must have at least one sequence. I modified the code: test = "/Users/teton/Desktop/bucky"
 where there are hundreds of files in the bucky folder.

Comment: Look at your `.fa` files. Do they have at least one sequence in them? I just ran the `SeqIO.convert()` code on a FASTA file I happened to have lying around with a single DNA sequence in it, and it returned a `.nex` file just fine, printing `1` (I'm guessing the number of sequences?).

Comment: please get some of .fa files from here, and see: https://db.tt/RS7ZJcwP

Comment: @Ramon [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72133618/clusters_with_nexus.zip) are the results, please check them to make sure they look OK.

Comment: My code ran without problem. I didn't do the `os.walk` business, I just used `os.listdir()` to create a list of files in the specified directory, then processed them.

Comment: @Ramon what do you get when you open a Python interpreter and run `import Bio; print(Bio.__version__)`? Also, what do you get when you run `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: Yes, MattDMo, its corret.  They are in NEXUS format. Thank you so much. I updated my code based on your code given for only current directory but I got the error I put in my question. import Bio; print(Bio.__version__) : 1.67

Comment: Can you provide your latest code in you answer, without os.walk.

Comment: Voila! I have them now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. NameError

You imported SeqIO but are calling seqIO.convert(). Python is case-sensitive. The line should read:

```
return SeqIO.convert(filename + '.fa', "fasta", filename + '.nex', "nexus", alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)
```

2. IOError: `for files in os.walk(test):`

IOError is raised when a file cannot be opened. It often arises because the filename and/ or file path provided does not exist.

`os.walk(test)` iterates through all subdirectories in the path `test`. During each iteration, `files` will be a list of 3 elements. The first element is the path of the directory, the second element is a list of subdirectories in that path, and the third element is a list of files in that path. You should be passing a filename to `process()`, but you are passing a list in `process(files)`.

You have implemented it correctly in this block `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(test):`. I suggest you implement it similarly in the `for` loop below.

3. You are adding `.fa` to your `filename`. Don't add `.fa`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I got this error!     return SeqIO.convert(filename + '.fa', "fasta", filename + '.nex', "nexus", alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 1003, in convert
    with as_handle(in_file, in_mode) as in_handle:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Bio/File.py", line 88, in as_handle
    with open(handleish, mode, **kwargs) as fp:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your comment. I suggest you edit your question to include the info you provided in the comment, so my answer makes sense for others who come upon this in the future.

Comment: Thank you. I will. In fact I dont need for subdirectories, just current directory is fine. now I get  this error saying :No such file or directory: '/Users/teton/Desktop/bucky/cluster1.fa.fa' why it assume an extra .fa? cluster1.fa exist.

Comment: If you don't need to recurse through subdirectories. Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968976/list-files-in-only-the-current-directory).

You're getting that error because, you've done `filename + '.fa'`. Don't add the `.fa`.

Comment: @Ramon because your parameters include `filename + ".fa"`. Either pass `cluster1` instead, or adjust your naming convention.

Comment: @Ramon Are you sure the path `/Users/teton/Desktop/bucky/cluster1.fa` exists? Do you have permissions to read the file?

Comment: This is the path: "/Users/teton/Desktop/bucky". cluster*.fa is the file.

Comment: Do some debugging. Try process("Users/teton/Desktop/bucky/cluster1.fa") outside of the `for` loop and see if it works. If that doesn't open try to just open the file in python by using `with open()`, and see if you can read it.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to update both the code and the error, this time for files in a directory only.