# How to convert a list of numpy files to a list of binary files?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to convert a list of numpy files in one directory to a list of binary files in an other directory with keeping the same order and the same names: the only thing that I need to change it is the extension in the name of the file; For example:

My directory where I put my numpy files:

```
   Tracenumber=01_Pltx1.npy
   Tracenumber=02_Pltx2.npy
   Tracenumber=03_Pltx3.npy
   Tracenumber=04_Pltx4.npy
   Tracenumber=05_Pltx5.npy
   Tracenumber=06_Pltx6.npy
```

The resulted directory where I put my binary files:

```
   Tracenumber=01_Pltx1.bin
   Tracenumber=02_Pltx2.bin
   Tracenumber=03_Pltx3.bin
   Tracenumber=04_Pltx4.bin
   Tracenumber=05_Pltx5.bin
   Tracenumber=06_Pltx6.bin
```

At first, I use to convert this code to convert one numpy file to a binary file:

```
import numpy as np
import struct

traces = np.load('C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_npy\\Tracenumber=01_Pltx1.npy')

f = open('C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_bin\\Tracenumber=01_Pltx1.bin', 'wb')
for t in traces.flatten():
    f.write(struct.pack('f', t))
f.close()
```

but now, I have tried this code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import struct
path_For_Binary_Files='C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_bin'
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_npy')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_npy'):
    for file in files:
       f=open(file,'r')
       trace= np.load(file)
       for t in trace.flatten():
         file.write(struct.pack(path_For_Binary_Files, t))
         file.close()
```

But it doesn't give me the result that I want. I have this error.

file.write(struct.pack(path_For_Binary_Files, t))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: you should describe what happens, what you expect to happen, how they differ and any errors you receive.

Comment: @pvg, could you take a look in the edited question please?

Comment: You shouldn't use \\ when your path is a raw string in the param to `os.walk`. Read the error message, that's obviously not a sane path.

Comment: No it isn't the problem, I try with one \ and I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.walk) for `os.walk`, you'll see that it does not simply return a list of files.

> For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).

You should change your `for` loop to read:

```
...
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\\Users\\user\\My_Test_Traces\\1000_Traces_npy'):
    for file in files:
        ...
```

However, it seems like you only want to parse the files in a single directory while `os.walk` is used to parse an entire directory tree.  To only get the files in your current directory you can use `os.listdir` and `os.path.isfile` as recommended in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968976/list-files-in-only-the-current-directory)

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('/your/path') if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, It gives me now this error:  file.write(struct.pack(path_For_Binary_Files, t))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: I  edit my  question based on your answer. Could you please take a look at the edited question?

Comment: @user6652926 You need to pause for a minute and consider the error message before asking for help.  `file` is a string in your code, `f` is the file  you have opened for writing.