# Correct my code please and tell me what i am doing wrong in it?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```py
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("palm.jpg")
cv2.imshow("palm", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Error in my screen:

> cv2.imshow("palm", image)
>
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: You're absolutely sure, that there is an image `palm.jpg` in the current working path?

Comment: @HansHirse Yes, it is in the current directory.

Comment: as i have already installed opencv then also i am getting error                       
 import cv2                                                                                                                 
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Answer (score 1):

Hey unfortunatly my reputation is not enough to comment, so I post this as an answer: I had this problem as well a couple of times. Every single time it turns out that I provided an incorrect path to the file.

I tried the code myself creating a palm.jpg in **the same directory as the script I'm opening it with**. It showed the BGR-Image as your code intends.

To me this means that opencv cannot open your "palm.jpg". To get more information you can try to set a breakpoint before the line

```
cv2.imshow("palm", image)
```

and have a look at the variable "image". If it does not contain meaningful information, you should have a look at [List files ONLY in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968976/list-files-only-in-the-current-directory) to check why palm.jpg is not in your working directory.

If it is on your working directory, maybe the palm.jpg is actually a palm.jpg.png (or similar).